# Possible to use Javascript to access the client side's network(knowingly)

Tags: javascript, forms, cross-domain, screen-scraping

I recently found an [exploit](http://lastyearswishes.com/blog/view/4fcff51b4aa5d8385420c706) in my router to basically give me root access. The catch? There is a `nonce` hidden form value that is randomly generated and must be sent in for it to work that makes it difficult to do "easily"

So basically I'm wanting to do something like this in javascript:

1. get `http://192.168.1.254/blah`
2. use a regex or similar to extract the nonce value
3. put the nonce value into a hidden field in the current page
4. submit the form by POST to `http://192.168.1.254/blah` complete with the nonce value and other form values I want to send in.

Is this at all possible using only HTML and Javascript? I'm open to things like "must save HTML file locally and then open", which I'm thinking is one way around the cross domain policy.

But anyway, is this at all possible? I'm hoping for this to be able to run from at least Firefox and Chrome. The audience for this is those with some technical know how.

Comment: What is a `nonce` value?

Comment: @Derek a hidden form element. It looks something like this in the HTML source of the modem's page: `<input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="815a0aaa0000176012db85d7d7cac9b31e749a44b6551d02" />`

Comment: You know now to do this from an app or script running on your machine, right?  What's the reason for doing this from a browser?

Comment: @jdigital I know how to do it. The thing is that I want to make this exploit easier so that other people can benefit and make their modem suck less. This is a notoriously awful modem that you can't replace. Just look at [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=nvg510)

Comment: You are asking the SO community for a way to break into a local network that is not your own.  This type of question is not appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: @jdigital don't assume that I have malicious purposes. I'm pretty sure I wouldn't have documented everything meticulously if I was going to secretly break into private networks.

Comment: Not necessarily questioning your intent. An answer here would provide instructions for others who may be less scrupulous.

Comment: @jdigital well, I'm really trying to find a method to do it that's easy. I don't expect that any solution is possible without some user intervention and implied permission though.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: I've rewritten this since my original answer was not correct.*

Since you can make an AJAX call to a local file, here is what you do.

"The AJAX page" is the page making the request.
"The requested page" is self explanatory.

1. You have your AJAX page **on your computer**. The AJAX pages calls the requested page **from your computer, in the same folder as itself**.
2. You instruct the user to **fetch the requested page from their router** and **put it in the same folder as the AJAX page**.
3. The cross-domain policy now no longer applies, since both files are in the same folder.
4. Your page can have a POST form where the `action` (target page) **is cross-domain and there should be no restrictions**.

If you can run PHP code on your page, try using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). This can make cross-domain requests.

Comment: AJAX GET is most certainly not exempt from the same-origin policy.

Comment: I didn't think so either. Tested it anyway with jQuery and epic failure

Comment: Ok, well it should work over a local network, right? Or am I really that ignorant? :P Otherwise, just save tha page locally first.

Comment: Nope.  The same-origin policy means you can **only** make an AJAX request *to the server the HTML page came from*.  Unless the local server also serves your HTML page, you won't be able to make a request.  For the same reason, saving the file locally will not work.  (*file:///...* `!=` *http​://192.168....*)

Comment: When I say "save locally" I mean copy it into the server you're running the AJAX call from.

Comment: The server in this case is a consumer router with a HTTP management console.  I'm not aware of any router's stock firmware that lets you stick your own HTML pages on its admin server.  (When I read "save locally", I take it to mean saving to the client hard drive.)

Comment: That is correct, assuming you are running the AJAX call from the same computer. You just need a copy of the page in the same folder you want to make the AJAX call from. However, the form needs to POST to the server like a normal form, just set the `action` attribute to the relevant server page.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to say.  Our theoretical AJAX call is being made from a page hosted on the local computer to a HTTP server running on a router, a remote device.  The same-origin policy will prevent this from happening.

Comment: What I'm saying is that as part of running this script, you instruct the user to fetch the AJAX-requested page, and stick it in the same folder. You will have already configured the AJAX call to request the same-named page, but in the same folder **as the page making the request**. I'm going to edit my original answer to show this more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done from a regular HTML page.  The Same-Origin policy will prevent you from connecting to the router.  (Saving the page locally won't help; browsers started heavily restricting what a local page can do several years ago.)

If you're really bent on making this happen from a browser, you could write an [extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html).   Origin restrictions do not apply to browser extensions.

Comment: Do you know if there are any extensions I could use to do this instead of writing my own? I think Greasemonkey(for Firefox) might be able to do something like this.

Comment: Writing a Chrome extension is easy (it's just HTML and JS); follow the [tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html).